# Why is NetworkManager package name upper case?

Tags: networkmanager, history, packaging

All other software packages are lower case, so why NetworkManager upper case?

Comment: I don't know if this is true, but I guess is it like this because for `tap` to work with both `network` and `Networkmanager` so if you type `net` + `tab` you get network, else(`Net` + `tab`) you get the other service

Comment: There are many other packages with capitalized package names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Red Hat Magazine: Introducing NetworkManager](https://web.archive.org/web/20140825090752/http://www.redhat.com/magazine/003jan05/features/networkmanager/) :

> Words with the creator
>
> NetworkManager creator and developer Dan Williams took time out of his hectically busy schedule to answer some questions.
>
> What's with those StudlyCaps, anyway?
> Well, coming from a Classic Mac OS background, in which everything was StudlyCaps, it is quite natural for me to use the Shift key, which many Linux programmers seem to run away from in fear. Which is quite silly, if you ask me. There's nothing to be afraid of. In any case, it also had to do with aesthetics. A daemon called network_manager just doesn't look good (using '_' instead of ' ' probably comes from the traditional Unix aversion to spaces in file names, which is also silly), and networkmanager is just pathetically hard to read, so it had to be NetworkManager.

Comment: Or it could be network-manager. On some systems, the package name or the service name is altered.

Comment: The Unix aversion to spaces in file names is 'silly'? Since the space is the Unix command line delimiter, permitting spaces in the filename (a common command line element)is idiotic.

Comment: What an arrogant *** Dan Williams is.   So he's better than Kernighan, Ritchie, Pike, Aho, et al?  Couldn't agree with you more, @StephenBoston

Answer (score 6):

This depends on the distribution. On Ubuntu, the name is not upper case:

```
$ dpkg -l|grep -i network-manager
ii  network-manager  0.9.8.8-0ubuntu7
```

The package name is written in upper case in Fedora (and thus Red Hat, CentOS, etc.), though. This is due to the fact that the [Fedora Naming Guidelines](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:NamingGuidelines) simply allow upper case package names. There are other packages with upper case names as well:

```
R-3.0.2-1.fc20.x86_64.rpm
TeXmacs-1.0.7.19-4.fc20.x86_64.rpm
```

Ubuntu follows Debian's naming guidelines, and these require lower case only: [Debian Policy Manual](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html#s-f-Source)

Comment: +1 good answer,but why this particular services is upper-cased

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you are mistaken. Package names are decided by the package manager maintainers, not by the specific projects. For example, all Debian/deb packages are lowercase, NetworkManager package even includes a dash, [`network-manager`](https://packages.debian.org/sid/network-manager), in the package name. Arch also use lowercase, but this time, without dash [`networkmanager`](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?name=networkmanager). RHEL-based distros packages follow the proper name of the project as package name, `NetworkManager`.

Also, you are also mistaken that NetworkManager is the only project with uppercase letters. DBus, GNOME, LaTeX, and several other projects use stylized versions of it's name using lower/uppercase letters.

So, it's up to the package maintainers to come up how their packages are named and if they support uppercase letters or not for the package names.

Comment: It just seems odd and out of place, was wondering the history behind it.